# Selecting the highest value in attribute from hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
h = {
  124 => ["shoes", "59.99"],
  456 => ["pants", "49.50"],
  352 => ["socks", "3.99"]
}
```

Each value has two elements. They are a name (e.g., `"shoes"`, `"pants"`, `"socks"`) and a price (e.g., `"59.99"`, `"49.50"`, and `"3.99"`). I need to select the value that has the highest price. That would be key `124` with price `"59.99"`. How do I select the hash with the highest price?

I tried this:

```
h.select{ |x| x[1] }.max
#=> [456, ["pants", "49.50"]]
```

But this gives me the max value and returns the key `456`.

Answer (score 6):

The most idiomatic would probably be this:

```
h.max_by { |_, v| v.last.to_f }
#=> [124, ["shoes", "59.99"]]
```

Comment: I suggest you show the return value: `#=> [124, ["shoes", "59.99"]]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can dig into the structure using parentheses like this:

```
h = {
  124 => ["shoes", "59.99"],
  456 => ["pants", "49.50"],
  352 => ["socks", "3.99"]
}

h.max_by{|_, (_, price)| price.to_f}
# => [124, ["shoes", "59.99"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first sort the hash:

```
sorted = hash.sort_by { |key, value| value[1].to_f }
# => [[352, ["socks", "3.99"]], [456, ["pants", "49.50"]], [124, ["shoes", "59.99"]]]
```

And then you can select the last pair:

```
sorted[-1]
# => [124, ["shoes", "59.99"]]
```

Comment: Or using `max_by`, `hash.max_by { |k,v| v.last.to_f }`

Comment: Thank you guys. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: You are sorting the values alphabetically, not by their numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t mind the keys, another option could be:

`h.values.map(&:reverse).max`

`#=> ["59.99", "shoes"]`

Comment: Notice that this compares the prices as strings, not as floats, and it is not certain whether the OP wanted that.